# Vuex and firebase listeners

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I'm using typescript and vuex-class decorators.

1. Within the `created()` hook in a vue component of my app I'm calling a vuex action `listenToDataXY` which itself calls a function in a separate api file where the firestore `onSnapshot` method/observer is placed.
2. If I understand it correctly, I can't just return a promise from that api function back to my vuex action because it will not trigger again in the future once new data is retrieved. So, instead of returning a promise, I want to just mutate the state from within the `onSnapshot` callback in the api file directly (is that ok?).
3. In order to do so, I imported `mutations` not to access the state directly. But I haven't figured out how to call a mutation function from a non-store-related file (api file) properly.
4. My vue component retrieves the updated value through getters.
5. How would you generally setup your code/files in a clean structured way in order to achieve the above (listening to firestore changes and update the state accordingly)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what I did is the following:

// actions.ts

```
getDataXY(context) {
    context.commit('setLoading', true)
    xyAPI.setupXYListener(context)
},

onXYChanged({ commit }, payload) {
    commit('setLoading', false)
    if (payload.xy) {
        commit('setXY', payload.xy)
    }
    if (payload.err) {
        commit('setErrorMessage', payload.err)
    }
},
```

// xyAPI.ts

```
setupXYListener(context: any) {
    xyCollection.onSnapshot(
        snapshot => {
            const xy = snapshot.docs[0].data()
            context.dispatch('onXYChanged', { xy: xy, err: null })
        },
        err => {
            context.dispatch('onXYChanged', { xy: null, err: err })
        }
    )
},
```

In case anyone sees a better architecture, structure or other improvements, I'm very thankful for comments.